# LocalReport Render hangs when run from a service like Quartz.Net

Tags: reporting-services, quartz.net, localreport

I have a `LocalReport` that I'm trying to render using the `Render` method that returns a byte array while running from Quartz.net.  Whenever it get's to the `Render` method the code hangs.  It runs correctly in a console app, only hanging during 'unattended' execution.

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, but is it hanging because it has nothing to render to in an unattended environment?

Comment: no, but thanks for trying.  What's frustrating of course is we are really struggling to replicate the problem.  It ONLY seems to happen in Quartz...